# Show button that covers HTML5 video

Tags: html5-video

I want to show a play button, that covers the whole of an html5 video that when you click initiates the video. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem is playing the video when the button is clicked, have a quick look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop) .
You simply get your video in javascript, and call `play` function.
For the button part, you can simply wrap your video in a div with the css `display:inline-block; position:relative` and a `<button>` tag with the css `position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;` so you would have

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<button style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;" onclick="playPause(); return false;">Click to start</button>
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```